How to integrate a Node.js server within a React Native app while ensuring APK export for production?
I am working on a React Native app, and I want to integrate a Node.js server directly into the app for certain functionalities. Specifically, I need to use libraries like ytdl-core, which are designed to work in a Node.js environment.
My Goals:

Embed the Node.js server within the React Native app.

Ensure that the app can still be exported as an APK for production and deployment.

Use Node.js libraries like ytdl-core within the integrated server.


I have looked into a few options, such as running a lightweight Node.js server within the app or using libraries like nodejs-mobile-react-native, but I am unsure about the feasibility and best practices for achieving this.
Steps I Have Followed:

Created a nodejs-assets folder in the React Native project.
Project Structure:
your-react-native-app/
├── nodejs-assets/
│   ├── nodejs-project/
│   │   ├── main.js         # Your Node.js server code
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── build-native-modules-MacOS-helper-script-node.sh
├── android/
├── ios/
└── package.json



Installed the required packages:
package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nodejs-mobile-react-native": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0"
  }
}



Created the Node.js server code:
nodejs-assets/nodejs-project/main.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const rn_bridge = require('rn-bridge');

app.use(express.json());

// Sample API endpoint
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Local server is running!' });
});

// Start the server
const SERVER_PORT = 3000;
app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server running on port ${SERVER_PORT}`);
});

// React Native communication
rn_bridge.channel.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('From RN:', msg);
});

rn_bridge.channel.send('Node was initialized.');



Updated React Native code to start the Node.js server:
App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import nodejs from 'nodejs-mobile-react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [serverMessage, setServerMessage] = useState('Starting server...');

  useEffect(() => {
    nodejs.start('main.js');

    nodejs.channel.addListener('message', (msg) => {
      console.log('From Node:', msg);
      setServerMessage(msg);
    });

    testLocalAPI();
  }, []);

  const testLocalAPI = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test');
      const data = await response.json();
      setServerMessage(data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API Error:', error);
      setServerMessage('Error connecting to local server');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Server Status: {serverMessage}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default App;



Made the following Android-specific configurations:
android/app/build.gradle
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude '**/libjsc.so'
        exclude '**/libc++_shared.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation project(':nodejs-mobile-react-native')
}


android/settings.gradle
include ':nodejs-mobile-react-native'
project(':nodejs-mobile-react-native').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/nodejs-mobile-react-native/android')


MainApplication.java
import com.janeasystems.rn_nodejs_mobile.RNNodeJsMobilePackage;

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new RNNodeJsMobilePackage()
    );
}




The Problem:
When running the app, I get the following error:
Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':nodejs-mobile-react-native'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':nodejs-mobile-react-native:classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully integrate the Node.js server in my React Native app?

I would try using a newer version of the Gradle tools. You can add a dependency inside buildscript. 2.2.3 is ancient.
I couldn’t see which version of RN you are using, but I’d make sure it’s officially supported by the module you’re using. They have some compatibility issues on some versions.
If you can’t succeed with nodejs-mobile-react-native, there is also a standard package nodejs-mobile, which should work, but without the RN helpers.

I have invested significant time and effort trying to resolve this issue, including consulting various resources and leveraging ChatGPT's assistance. I also referred to the solution provided in this shared link: https://chatgpt.com/share/676bc850-8e70-8013-8bf0-16e39e885ec8. However, I have not been able to find a satisfactory solution so far. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
